# Microsoft SQL server edit imported file

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I'm new in SQL server. I have imported an Excel file into my SQL Server Database. There is a column with the Name of `myDate` and it shows dates like: `20.07.2018`.

I did right click on my table, then I chose "Select 1000 rows" and added the convert code there but it didn't work! I have the same result as before! (the Format didn't change). Is there anyone who knows why it didn't change?

Here is what I wrote:

```
select convert (varchar,[dateColumn],102) as date2
from [test1].[dbo].[change1]
Go
```

Comment: I assume `[dateColumn]` is a `varchar` to begin with?

Comment: When you imported teh excel file, it stored the myDate column as varchar. The right thing to do is to update the table changing the datatype to date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having a column's name as myDate doesn't mean its datatype is date, datetime or datetime2. Apparently your data type is VARCHAR. You should use date, datetime or datetime2 for such a column.

For conversion you can do it like this:

```
SET DATEFORMAT DMY;

SELECT convert (varchar, TRY_CAST(myDate AS DATE),102) as date2 
from [test1].[dbo].[change1];
```

(Again this is questionable why would you convert to a varchar).

Comment: Always, always, **ALWAYS** specify the length of any string datatype you use.

Comment: @SMor, why do we need it here (in turn why ALWAYS as you are shouting)?